# Passing a string to a function but quotes are causing an issue

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a string to a function like this and it works fine

```
players = pool.get_players('Trevor Zegras', 'Adam Henrique', 'Troy Terry', 'Cam Fowler', 'Dmitry Kulikov', 'John Gibson')
```

However I am trying to pass a variable
like this and it doesn't work, I think because of extra quotes because of the string.
This returns an error

```
group = "'Trevor Zegras', 'Adam Henrique', 'Troy Terry', 'Cam Fowler', 'Dmitry Kulikov', 'John Gibson'"
players = pool.get_players(group)
```

Is there a way to pass it the variable without the quotes? I tried to remove them, but am unable to. I tried a tuple, but that failed as well.

Comment: That's not "a" string, that's a series of string arguments.

Comment: If you show what you actually tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: PSA: When programming you can't just make stuff up and expect it to work. You *must* check your reference manual on how to do things correctly.

Comment: Care to describe what the error is you're asking for help with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function doesn't take one string argument, it takes multiple arguments.

When you use a string as an argument, it's not parsed into separate arguments; it's not like a macro that reparsed the result of substituting the string.

Put them in a list, not a string, then use the spread operator to turn them into separate arguments.

```
group = ['Trevor Zegras', 'Adam Henrique', 'Troy Terry', 'Cam Fowler', 'Dmitry Kulikov', 'John Gibson']
players = pool.get_layers(*group)
```